# Date Filter is not working properly MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

My date filter works just fine when I put it into a separate view, but I am having trouble merging it with the other filters and I am not sure where I am going wrong. All other filters are working. Could you please take a look and let me know what I need to change when I join my query to the others to get it working and merged? Thank you!

Here is what it looks like in a separate Controller, and this works in the view:

```
public ActionResult DateFilter(FormCollection DatePicker)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime end = DateTime.Today;

        if (DatePicker.Count > 0)
        {
            start = DateTime.Parse(DatePicker["startDate"].ToString());
            end = DateTime.Parse(DatePicker["endDate"].ToString());
        }
        var Issue = db.Issue.Where(d => d.DateCreated >= start && d.DateCreated <= end).Select(i => new IssueViewModel
        {
            Name = i.Name,
            Description = i.Description,
            DateCreated = i.DateCreated,
            DateCompleted = i.DateCompleted,
            //ect.
        }).ToList();

        ViewBag.Issue = Issue;

        return View();
    }
```

Here is what it looks like merged with the other filters:

```
private static IQueryable<Issue> FilterDeviceList(List<Issue> issues, FormCollection DatePicker, string EHP, string IssueKey)
    {
        var query = issue.AsQueryable();

        //COPYING STARTS HERE
        DateTime start = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime end = DateTime.Today;

        if (DatePicker.Count > 0)
        {
            start = DateTime.Parse(DatePicker["startDate"].ToString());
            end = DateTime.Parse(DatePicker["endDate"].ToString());
        }
            query = query.Where(d => d.DateCreated >= start != null && d.DateCreated <= end != null && d.DateCreated == Convert.ToDateTime(DatePicker));

            //COPYING ENDS HERE

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EHP))
            query = query.Where(i => i.EHPP != null && i.EHPP == (EHP == "1" ? false : true));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IssueKey))
            query = query.Where(i => i.IssueKey != null && i.IssueKey.Contains(IssueKey));

return query;
}
```

If anyone needs to see the view or the controller that calls IQueryable, please let me know and I can post it, but I think this should be sufficient. Thank you again! :)

Comment: What specifically is not working ? BTW, I am not quite sure what this expression do `d.DateCreated >= start != null`

Comment: I have tried doing that without setting it not equal to null, but that doesn't work either. I was just playing around with it. The method in the first controller returns the date to date filter properly, but the method in the merged IQueryable controller is not returning anything, and I'm not sure what in the line needs to be changed or where it should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static IQueryable<Issue> FilterDeviceList(List<Issue> issues, FormCollection DatePicker, string EHP, string IssueKey)
{
    var query = issues.AsQueryable();

    DateTime start,end;

    if (DatePicker.Count > 0)
    {
        start = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePicker["startDate"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        end = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePicker["endDate"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    // assuming start and end date will not be null
    if(start != null && end !=null)
     {
        query = query.Where(d => d.DateCreated >= start && d.DateCreated <= end);
    }  

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EHP))
        query = query.Where(i => i.EHPP != null && i.EHPP == (EHP == "1" ? false : true));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IssueKey))
        query = query.Where(i => i.IssueKey != null && i.IssueKey.Contains(IssueKey));

     return query;
}
```